# typeFromString Action throws exception-uima ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

The below code throws the error: **Action "typeFromString" is not defined.**

```
CW{-> typeFromString("Person")};
```

From the documentation, I understand that 'Person' is the name of an annotation that need not be declared already using DECLARE statement and that all CW's will be marked as 'Person'. Please correct me if I'm wrong and let me know how to resolve the above error.

Comment: Person does not need to be declared, but the type must be in the type system of the cas. The error indicates that the extension `TypeFromStringFunctionExtension` in not configured in the analysis engine.

Comment: @PeterKluegl    TypeFromStringFunctionExtension is already configured in the typesystem and I added the type "Person" in the typesystem.Now it works fine .But still it displays error in the workspace.

Comment: type "Person" is getting removed from the typesystem for the next run.How can I set the type permernantly.

Comment: Whether I need to add the type explicitly Can you elaborate  "typeFromString " Action.

Comment: I added an answer. Sorry, I should have read the question more carefully. It's a function not an action.

Comment: How to add hte type depends on your environment, on how you use UIMA or Ruta. For testing, you can simple declare the type in your script: `DECLARE Person;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. The type function `typeFromString` throws an exception if the type is not defined in the typesystem of the CAS (should be fixed). Short names work if they are unambiguous.
2. The editor reports a false error for the type function if it is used as an implicit action. This can be avoided by using `CW{-> MARK(typeFromString("Person"))};`. `typeFromString` is not an action but a function returing a type.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*